# Getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption error

Tags: java, swing, encryption, netbeans, public-key-encryption

I am new to java, so please forgive me for silly questions

1) my project moved from netbeans 6 to 8

2) jdk moved from 6u45 to 8u11

3) After successful setup to new environment when I debug

> got error: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block
>   incomplete in decryption

Stacktrace:

> com.alstom.tsoft.controller.system.ParameterTablesController$LoadOfflineWorker
>   - [javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:121),
>   javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:192),
>   com.alstom.tsoft.crypto.CryptoManager.decryptString(CryptoManager.java:146),
>   com.alstom.tsoft.io.CryptedFieldReader.readField(CryptedFieldReader.java:58),

4) It never happened in previous `environment(jdk6 and netbeans 6)`, that is the only change in project.

We are using following input:

```
private static final String ALGO_TYPE = "AES";
private static final String ALGO_FULL_NAME = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String ALGO_PROVIDER = "BC";

public String encryptString(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchProviderException,
       NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException,IOException {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(
           new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()),
           getEncryptionCipher());                
    int b;
    while ( ( b = cis.read() ) != -1 ) {           
       String twoHexDigit = String.format("%1$02x",b);           
       //m_logger.info(":"+b+":"+twoHexDigit.toUpperCase());
       output.append(twoHexDigit.toUpperCase());
    }
    return output.toString();
}
//Dencryption
public String decryptString(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchProviderException,
       NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException,IOException {       
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();                        
    byte[] inputBytes = convertHexStringToByte(input);        

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(
           new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes), 
           getDecryptionCipher());                      
    int b;
    while ( ( b = cis.read() ) != -1 ) {
       output.append(new Character((char)b));
    }                                              
    return output.toString();
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong and how to debug

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you need to add Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength to you JRE. Download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: Both the jars are already present. This error went off when i create .exe and run through

Comment: First fix your stream handling, using try-with-resources. This exception may have always happened, but `CipherInputStream` has (had) the annoying property of shuffling exceptions "under the carpet" (i.e. catching them and then ignoring them).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Maarten, But its already handled in the calling function, could you please suggest what to use instead of CipherInputStream.

Comment: I read that, switching between jdk from 32 bit to 64 bit also creating problem and use of CipherInputStream also some times creates problem ?    Does any one having similar problem